# How to get timespans between entities from timed log table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a log table to store user's login/logout logs. My goal is to calculate how many times each user logged in and logined-times for each login.

I'm working on PostgreSQL database. Log table has log_id(PK), user_id(FK), login_state, created_time. login_state column is enum type and its value is either 'login' or 'logout'.

For now, I used self join on Log table like below.

```
SELECT A.log_id, A.user_id, A.login_state, A.created_time, B.log_id, B.login_state, B.created_time, (B.created_time-A.created_time) elapsedtime 
FROM logtable A INNER JOIN logtable B ON (A.login_state='login' AND B.login_state='logout') 
WHERE (A.user_id=B.user_id) AND (A.created_time<=B.created_time);
```

I got some right records but there are also wrong records.

I think maybe join couldn't be a solution. For each login entity, only one logout entity should be matched but I couldn't write the right query statement for this.

The best result could be a collection of login-logout pairs and it's elapsed time for each user.

Need some helps. Thanks.

============== Add some sample data and expected results =========

Sample Log Table

[image: Sample Log Table]

Expect Results
[image: Expect Results]

DB Fiddler for test
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vz6EyKKTg6PWs1X4HbTspB/0

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: @S-Man okay, I add some images.. Expect results is mocked image.

Comment: Please do not add images. We cannot copy the data for testing. Please add copyable code or a fiddle like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f9832a7cccd97827af98e45f751609e9

Comment: @S-Man added! [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vz6EyKKTg6PWs1X4HbTspB/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vz6EyKKTg6PWs1X4HbTspB/0) Please beware that user table is renamed as myuser table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8f0e33aa6f4ffd5037efcb99d47fb9ee)

You can use the [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to get the next value into the current record.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    logout_time - created_time AS elapsed_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead(created_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_time) as logout_time
    FROM logtable
) s
WHERE login_state = 'login'
ORDER BY created_time
```